# Required em checkbox

Tags: html

Bom dia, estou aqui com uma dúvida relativamente a obrigar que a minha checkbox seja preenchida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu estou a utilizar o required e funciona em todos os campo menos na checkbox.

**Codigo do campo nome (funcional)** - 
`<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome..." required=" " >`

**Codigo da checkBox (nao funcional)** -
 `<label style="margin-top:10px;" class="checkbox"><input required=" " type="checkbox" name="termos" value="1"><i> </i>Eu li e aceito os <a href="/termos_condicoes">termos e condições</a></label>`

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir esse problema, o `required` funciona normalmente no checkbox, desde que qualquer outro `required` anterior tenha sido preenchido corretamente. Aqui tem uma print: https://i.ibb.co/F5WMK47/capturar2.png, usando o código que você mesmo indicou.

Comment: Por que usar `required=" "` e não apenas `required`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando Javascript você consegue validar o checkbox. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
 <title>Validar checkbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
  <p><input id="termos" type="checkbox" required name="terms"> Eu aceito os termos e condições</u></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
 </form>
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var myCheckbox = document.getElementById("termos");
    var myCheckboxMsg = "Você precisa aceitar os termos e condições";
    myCheckbox.setCustomValidity(myCheckboxMsg);
    myCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.valueMissing ? myCheckboxMsg : "");
    }, false);
 }, false);
 
</script>
```

Comment: resolvido, muito obrigado!